# VBA applying function to each cell in range

Tags: vba

I need to write macro or function or whatever in VBA, what will apply a function with arguments (e.g. vlookup) on a rangeof cells. I thought it can be done by macro, but there I could not use arguments for vlookup, so I dont know any way how to do it. Is it possible?

For example:

I want to have this: 
vlookup(A1;G1:H50;2;0) in cell B1 and 
vlookup(A2;G1:H50;2;0) in cell B2 and so on, to e.g. B10

but I want to write formula only once and let other cells to be filled automaticaly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *but there I could not use arguments for vlookup*  **<<** Why do you say this?  Please show the code you have currently attempted to use, so that we may recommend solution(s).

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, because this is my second thing what I try to write in VBA, but I thought that in macros can not be used input arguments, so they also cannot be used in function used in macro. E.g. applying division by 2 to range is easy to be used on range by macro, because there are no arguments needed, but what should I do if I need to work with arguments inside the macro?

Comment: Yes, I think you're misunderstanding some concepts. You can most certainly use VBA to insert formulas (with arguments defined inside the macro procedure).  Macros themselves generally cannot require arguments (however subroutine procedures *can* require arguments, they will just not be available from the Macros menu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Application.VLookup just like this following this example     http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-vba/:

```
Sub SetValues(columnToChange As String, columnToLookup As String, range As String, startColumn As Integer, endColumn As Integer)
    For number = startColumn To endColumn Step 1
       valueLookup = columnToLookup + CStr(number)
       valueToChange = columnToChange + CStr(number)
       Sheets("yourSheetName").Range(valueToChange).value = Application.VLookup(valueLookup, range, 2, 0)
    Next number

End Sub
```

If you want to call them, create another subroutine without parameters that you can call from a button click for instance.

```
Sub DoStuff()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim valueLookup as String
    Dim valueToChange as String
    Dim range as String
    Dim firstColumn as Integer
    Dim lastColumn as Integer

Label1:
    valueLookup = InputBox("Enter the column to lookup")
    valueToChange = InputBox("Enter the column to change")
    range = InputBox("Enter the range of the lookup")
    firstColumn = CInt(InputBox("Enter the first column number to lookup"))
    lastColumn = CInt(InputBox("Enter the last column number to lookup"))
    Call SetValues(valueToChange, valueLookup, range, firstColumn, lastColumn)
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox("One value has an error in it.")
    Resume Label1:
End Sub
```

Comment: All of this is okay, but point of my problem is, that I need to make it in way that I can use it each time with different arguments (different data to be vlookuped), not fixed in the macro

Comment: @lulish89 You mean like this?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I wrote something similar but I didnt know how to call this macro in excel, and I still didnt know it. Can you adviced me?

Comment: When I try to put macro DoStuff to VBA the lines with SetValues are colored red and I dont know why. Despite this, isnt it the situation when values for arguments are hardcoded in macro? It is another macro but I see them hardcoded here, and not like I requsted to set them in excel. Maybe I am wrong and it works in different way but I dont know how to test it.

Comment: Isnt it the "InputBox" the way how to get these arguents to the macro?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, here is one way (you'll have to change the delimiter to match your country settings, and adjust where you want the formula to go, I just put in B1:B10 as an example):

```
Sheet1.Range("B1:B10").Formula = "=vlookup(A1,$G$1:$H$50,2,0)"
```

This bit of code will write the formula to the range B1:B10 on sheet1, which has the same effect of putting the formula in the B1 and then "dragging" it down to B10.  What makes this work is that Excel has the built in functionality of auto-incrementing a formula references based on whether or not the range is preceded by a $ symbol.

If a column reference has a $ in front, it will not increment as the formula is dragged across  columns.  If the $ is in front of the row reference, it will not increment as the formula is dragged down.

So looking back at my proposed formula, you can see that the A1 will increment as the formula is dragged to B2, B3, B4, etc...auto-incrementing the look up value to be cell A2, A3, A4, respectively.  The look up range does not change at all because both the column and the row references are preceded by a $.

If you run the code I gave you, you'll see that you should have the expected results of only writing one formula, but changing the look up range through the built in auto incrementing functionality.

--------------------More edits based on comments--------------------
To do what you want, you don't need VBA at all (even though you initially requested a VBA / macro solution).  You can put the formula in a cell and drag it down to how ever far down you want it to go.  Please take a look at this link to see if it helps answer your questions:

[How to fill data automatically in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-HP001216366.aspx)

Comment: But my problem is not this, but to be able to use it each time with different arguments, not fixed in the code. I am sorry if it wasnt clean from my question

Comment: @lulish89 can you give examples of the arguments?  Are they hard coded in vba, from a range on a worksheet, etc.  You're going to have to provide more details...

Comment: OK, I try to explain it on an example with vlookup. I need something like modifiedvlookup(A1,$G$1:$H$50,2,0) which perform vlookup with arguments specified above except A1 (this will change according actual cell), on specified range, e.g. B1:B10. I write this formula in cell B1 and it will perform vlookup(A1,$G$1:$H$50,2,0) on cell B1, vlookup(A2,$G$1:$H$50,2,0) on cell B2, vlookup(A3,$G$1:$H$50,2,0) on cell B3, etc. So I need to have formula which will perform 10 vlookups when I write it to first cell. Is it understandable?

Comment: @lulish89 Did you at least try what I posted?  It does exactly what you're asking...

Comment: I am sorry, it is misunderstading. I ask this question because I didnt know about possibility of using macros with arguments. When you answered me with this code I considered it as solution only for applying function on range of cells but with arguments hard coded in macro, because you write only this part and didnt tell how to give user-specified arguments from excel here and I also didnt know it. This is the reason why I didnt try it, I was preparing to ask you how to write whole macro with arguments to be able to try it.

Comment: That's a fair criticism and I'll update my answer appropriately.

Comment: @lulish89 please see my updated answer with explanation.  Hope that helps clarify what the macro is doing.  If not, let me know and I'll try to explain it differently.

Comment: I see there one problem, maybe I am wrong but I still dont know how to call it from excel. I refer to one of the things I write in question:"I want to write formula only once (to one cell) and let other cells to be filled automaticaly". From your answer I still didnt know how to do it. In the answer below is solution with whole macro with arguments, which uses similar code as you did, but I dont know how to call it in excel and put arguments here. Thats my problem.

Comment: @lulish89  Ok, one more edit and that's about all I can provide at this point.  Hope it gets you there!

Comment: I know about the option you wrote to the solution, but I need to do it in VBA

Comment: @lulish89 I've provided both a VBA and non-VBA solution.  If you're not sure how to use macros, please look here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/run-a-macro-HP010342865.aspx